# Your render method should have return statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, product, card

```
class App extends React.Component {


  render() {

    productList.map((product) => {

      return (
        <div className="mainContainer">
          <div className="titel">{product.title}</div>
          <div className="type">{product.type}</div>
          <div className="producer">{product.producer}</div>
          <div className="unit">{product.unit}</div>

          <div className="prisContainer">
            <div className="pris">{product.price}</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}


export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you aren't returning anything from within the render function. Returning the mapped result will solve the problem if you are on v16 or above of react.

```
class App extends React.Component {


  render() {

    return productList.map((product) => {

      return (
        <div className="mainContainer">
          <div className="titel">{product.title}</div>
          <div className="type">{product.type}</div>
          <div className="producer">{product.producer}</div>
          <div className="unit">{product.unit}</div>

          <div className="prisContainer">
            <div className="pris">{product.price}</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}


export default App;
```

If you are on a lower version, wrap the result of map function within a div

```
render() {

    return <div>{productList.map((product) => {

      return (
        <div className="mainContainer">
          <div className="titel">{product.title}</div>
          <div className="type">{product.type}</div>
          <div className="producer">{product.producer}</div>
          <div className="unit">{product.unit}</div>

          <div className="prisContainer">
            <div className="pris">{product.price}</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    })}<div>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a seperate variable that runs the map and returns the content and then add the variable in the return statement within the render

```
render() {
return (
 <div> {content} </div>
 )
}
```